# DbGeography mapping in OnModelCreating

Tags: entity-framework, orm, poco, fluent-interface

I have a class with properties Latitude and Longitude.
I use `EF 5` for persistence so DbGeography is a good choice, but I don't want that my entity class library has reference with `EF`.

Is it possible to map into `OnModelCreating` this rule so that db table has `DbGeography` while into my class remain Lat and Lon ? With fluent api I mean.

In case of true , when I call get method of my repository , the inverse mapping ( from DBGeo to Lat and Lon)  is automatic ?

Thanks in advance
Luca

Comment: Was you able to resolve this? I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to leverage the features of `DbGeography` type in your application, there isn't any real benefit to storing the coordinate in the form of `DbGeography`. Just use the decimal type with the precision needed for your application.